# How to create an np.array from another np.array if the element of a third np.array of the same index is zero?

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

Suppose I have

```py
a = np.array([0, 1, 3, 0])
b = np.array([[4,5],[7,8],[9,5],[8,2]])
```

How can I create a third array

```
c = [[4,5],[8,2]]
```

with a `list` comprehension?

Comment: You only want a comprehension, not the `numpy` solution `b[~a.astype('bool')]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the best (and fastest) way of doing this is without list comprehensions, and using boolean indexing:

```py
c = b[a==0]
```

If you want to use list comprehensions, besides [the option presented by @politinsa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71096305/17457042), you can use `zip`, that is useful when you have to go through more than one iterable at the same time (in this case, `a` and `b`):

```py
c = np.array([b_d for (b_d, a_d) in zip(b, a) if a_d == 0])
```

When you want to iterate through elements and get the index of each element, `enumerate` can be cleaner than a `range(len(iterable))` (although not necessarily faster):

```py
c = np.array([b_d for i,b_d in enumerate(b) if a[i] == 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

`c = np.array([b[i] for i in range(len(b)) if a[i] == 0])`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think there is a typo in the last ')]'
c = np.array([b[i] for i in range(len(b)) if a[i] == 0])